# win.length got wrong result while using pattern in EPL Nesper

Tags: design-patterns, nesper

I have problem with windows length.

**My condition:**
1-Output will trigger if event happen within length 3
2-Output dismiss if event happen after length 3

**Example:**
 Event Sequence: 
 1:A
 2:B
 3:C
 4:D
 5:E
 6:A
 7:C
 8:D
 9:E
 10:F
 11:B
 **Event Rule:**  Z = A --> B
 **Expected Output**: Z will occurred at index number 2 since win:length(3)

**My Problem**: The output Z also triggered at index number 11 eventhought it exceeds win:length(3)

**My simple code**:

```
"SELECT a.index, a.event FROM pattern [every (a=EventList(event=A) -> b=EventList(event=B))].win:length(3)"
```

May anyone help me to figure out how to to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The "pattern[...].window" does not limit pattern matches to what is in the window. If you want to limit pattern matches to what is in the window that is what match-recognize does.

See [table](http://espertech.com/esper/release-5.4.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#match-recognize-compare-pattern) under data window.

("pattern[...].window" is handy for other cases for example for joins or for iterating)